# Function not recognised on dragstart event

Tags: javascript

A function getId is not getting called on dragstart in html. The code looks simple and correct, I am not sure why it isn't getting  called

HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: top; border-right: 2px solid darkcyan;" id="sidebar">
            <div><a id="newTask" title="Add new task" draggable="true" ondragstart=getId(this.id)><img src="task.png" /></a></div>
        </div>
<div id="canvas" tabindex="0"></div>
<div id="tabbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 803);

    function getId(id)
    {
        var shapeId = id;
        console.log(shapeId);
    }
};
```

Its throwing an error saying: `Uncaught ReferenceError: getId is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your `getId` function within the `onload` function - ie it's not in a scope where it can be invoked via the event.

Move it outside the `onload` function:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 803);


};

function getId(id)
{
    var shapeId = id;
    console.log(shapeId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 803);
};

    function getId(id)
    {
        var shapeId = id;
        console.log(shapeId);
    }
```

Function `getId`is not visible due to function scope it's defined. Make it global. (Further refactoring will be required).